# Is there any reason to create an array for only 1 element?

Tags: java, arrays, double

I just found this code snippet and was wondering if there is any specific reason why the value is stored in a double[1](http://code.cytoscape.org/redmine/projects/cy3-impl/repository/revisions/ae36b88b1a5a8b06dd438dc17babcf3d6fe0bfdc/entry/layout-cytoscape-impl/src/main/java/csapps/layout/algorithms/bioLayout/BioLayoutKKAlgorithmTask.java) array instead of just a "normal" double variable?

```
double[] potentialEnergy = new double[1];

if (potentialEnergy[0] != 0.0)
    throw new RuntimeException();
```

Also, are there actually any cases where the initial value of a double is not 0.0 so you need to check that specifically?

For context: I recently started to read about graph visualisation and stumbled upon the [sourcecode](http://code.cytoscape.org/redmine/projects/cy3-impl/repository/revisions/ae36b88b1a5a8b06dd438dc17babcf3d6fe0bfdc/entry/layout-cytoscape-impl/src/main/java/csapps/layout/algorithms/bioLayout/BioLayoutKKAlgorithmTask.java) of an implementation for the kamada/kawai force directed algorithm. In there, starting at line 311, i found those 3 lines of code and didn't find any reason for it to be an array:

Comment: My guess would be that `potentialEnergy` is used later in the code, and that usage expects it to be in the form of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any reason to create an array for only 1 element?

Yes: If you're passing it into a method that will provide a value by putting it in the array (rather than providing a value by returning it, perhaps because it returns some other value).

Generalizing that: If you're providing it to an API that expects an array, even if it's just a single-element array.

> Also, are there actually any cases where the initial value of a double is not 0.0 so you need to check that specifically?

No, a freshly-allocated array contains elements with all bits off (which are zeros when it's a `double` array [or an array any other numeric type, including `char`], `false` for arrays of `boolean`, and `null` for arrays of a reference type).

Comment: @Falkreon - Thanks, but since that content isn't **in** the question, it doesn't make sense for it to be in the answer.